# expected specifier-qualifier-list before std

Tags: c++

```
typedef struct _stResult {
  std::string x;  
  int y;
  struct _stResult *next;  
} strResult;
```

In this structure i am getting the following error **expected specifier-qualifier-list before std**. What does this error mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this error mean: "error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'type_name'"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608175/what-does-this-error-mean-error-expected-specifier-qualifier-list-before-type)

Comment: Note that the `typedef struct x {} name;` style is useful in C, but not C++. In C++ you normally just want `struct name{};` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::string` is not declared. If you `#include <string>` at the top, the code compiles.

Comment: i included #include <string>. it says no such file or directory.

Comment: @SPB, if you don't include it, you can't use it. Seems your compiler has it's paths set up wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Did you forget to `#include <string>` ?

The compiler obviously doesn't recognize `std::string` as a type.