# Error: 'class name' redeclared as different kind of symbol?

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, forward-declaration

I was facing the same error as asked in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608175/what-does-this-error-mean-error-expected-specifier-qualifier-list-before-type)

I overcome with this error by solution of  declaring class ahead of time in my .h file with the `class parameter`

I am having `FFTBufferManager.h and FFTBufferManager.cpp` file and using it in `HomeView.h and HomeView.mm` file

`class FFTBufferManager,CAStreamBasicDescription,DCRejectionFilter;`

But now I am having error as

```
#include "FFTBufferManager.h"
#include "aurio_helper.h"
#include "CAStreamBasicDescription.h"

class CAStreamBasicDescription,FFTBufferManager;  //here it shows this error
   EXpected Unqualified-id befor ',' token


@interface HomeView 
{
    FFTBufferManager*           fftBufferManager;
//it shows erros 
 EXpected Unqualified-id befor ',' token
    ISO c++ forbids declaration of FFTBufferManager with no type
```

}

```
    @property FFTBufferManager*     fftBufferManager;
 //shows error
'FFTBufferManager' is not a type
```

Comment: Here I am having same error for my class `FFTBufferManager` which is `.cpp` file and I am importing it in my iphone project

Comment: just to be absolutely clear, you're using both C++ and Objective-C in your project?

Comment: yes i am having `.h and .cpp` files and using them in my `.h and .mm` files

Answer (score 2):

I'm gathering you're using both C++ and Objective-C.

I'd suggest renaming all your `.cpp` and `.m` files in which Objective-C and C++ code are meeting to use the extension `.mm` - this tells the compiler to use "Objective-C++" rules, and will stop a lot of compiler troubles.

Also, it seems `CAStreamBasicDescritpion` is a C++ class - you'll have to forward-declare it with `class CAStreamBasicDescritpion;`, **not** `@class CAStreamBasicDescritpion;` (note, no "at" sign) - the second form is only for forward-declaring *Objective-C* classes. This I suspect is the root cause of the particular error you have observed.

**EDIT** in response to comment: I'm not sure about your first new issue - that should work fine so long as both `FFTBufferManager` and `CAStreamBasicDescription` are C++ classes. As to your second one, depending on where exactly that line of code is (`CAStreamBasicDescription thruFormat;`) you may need to include the header rather than just the forward-declare: you're declaring an instance of `CAStreamBasicDescription` here, and the compiler needs to know its structure to do so.

Comment: tried your suggestion as with `class FFTBufferManager,CAStreamBasicDescription;` but it gives `expected unqualified-id before ',' token` and also where I declared my object as `CAStreamBasicDescription thruFormat;` it gives `ISO:C++ forbids delcaration of CAStreamBasicDescription with no type`

Comment: is it that, we cannot declare two classes together as `class FFTBufferManager,CAStreamBasicDescription`? because it is giving first error at ','

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare more than one class at a time.

Change your declarations to

```
class CAStreamBasicDescription;
class FFTBufferManager;
```

The compiler is looking for an `unqualified-id` because it believes that you're declaring a variable of type `CAStreamBasicDescription`, so it expects a variable name where you gave it a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to create a class that already exists in one of the Cocoa frameworks.