# "expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘*’ token" error in variadic function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trying to write a function which will configure a peripheral of a microcontroller in C. To do so, I have used `va_arg`. Here is the function:

```
void init_peripheral(int ID, ...){
    va_list device;
    va_start(device, ID);
    io * temp; // No error here
            //io is a structure 
            //IO, USART, LCD are 01, 02, 03.
    (*temp).portB.set = set_portB;

    if( ID == IO ){
        io* config_io; // error:expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘*’ token
        config_io = va_arg(device, *io);
        (*config_io).portB.set = set_portB;
        (*config_io).portB.clr = clr_portB;
        (*config_io).portB.mkin = mkin_portB;
        (*config_io).portB.mkout = mkout_portB;

        (*config_io).portC.set = set_portC;
        (*config_io).portC.clr = clr_portC;
        (*config_io).portC.mkin = mkin_portC;
        (*config_io).portC.mkout = mkout_portC;

        (*config_io).portD.set = set_portD;
        (*config_io).portD.clr = clr_portD;
        (*config_io).portD.mkin = mkin_portD;
        (*config_io).portD.mkout = mkout_portD;
    }

    else if( ID == LCD ){       
        lcd *config_lcd;
        config_lcd = va_arg(device, *lcd);
         //Set necessary params here
    }

    else if( ID == USART){
        usart *config_usart;
        config_usart = va_arg(device, *usart);
        (*config_usart).init = usart_init;
        (*config_usart).transmit = usart_transmit;
        (*config_usart).receive = usart_receive;
    }


    va_end(device);
}
```

I don't get an error for the line `io * temp`, but I do get an error for `io * config_io;`
Here is the `io` struct:

```
struct __io__{
    struct __port__ portB;
    struct __port__ portC;
    struct __port__ portD;
};
typedef struct __io__ io;
```

Comment: Side note, you are dereferencing an unitialised pointer (`temp`), which is undefined behaviour and probably a seg fault.

Comment: Could you show exactly how `io` is defined? Any macros involved?

Comment: Perhaps you have a problem with your `typedef`. Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/608185/1344760).

Comment: The second argument to `va_arg` should be a type.  `*io` is not a type.  `io*` is, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is actually in the next line, with the `va_arg` macro. You're sending a dereferenced pointer instead of a type:

```
config_io = va_arg(device, *io);       // Should be io*

config_lcd = va_arg(device, *lcd);     // Should be lcd*

config_usart = va_arg(device, *usart); // Should be usart*
```

Here's [your code](http://ideone.com/BJAja), which has the compilation problems.
Here's [the fixed version](http://ideone.com/dnRla).

Comment: Oops, feeling dumb. Thank you so much for that.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks correct. And since you can declare `temp`, I see no reason why `io_config` should suddenly fail. What you should try:

1. Add `#under config_io` before the function; maybe a macro `config_io` is defined.
2. Replace `io` with `struct __io__` just to see whether that would compile. If it doesn't move the variable declaration outside the `if()` block; maybe your compiler version doesn't support it.
3. Tell the compiler to show you the preprocessed source code (i.e. after all macros have been expanded). Maybe that gives you a hint.